# Issues using aws ssm parameter for private repository authentication in task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-ssm, ecs-taskdefinition

So I am using ghcr as my container registry and having some images there. Trying to deploying those image using aws ecs and task definitions through terraform.
In task definition, I have specified the image url and repository credentials. To access my image, I need to provide my ghcr username and token. I have stored my ghcr username and token as json object, in aws secret manager and aws ssm paraters as well.

```
{username: xxx,password: xxx}
```

If I use aws secret manager key arn as credentialsParameter, it works. If I use aws ssm parameter arn there, it is giving error.
How to use ssm parameter which has text as above json object in credentialsParameter ? Is there is anyway or workaround to do that ? or I should use only secret manager key arn.

Comment: Interestingly, the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-repositorycredentials.html) only mentions "secret" for this field, while the [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition) mentions both "secret" and "systems manager parameter". Can you provide the full error message you're getting?

Comment: When I use ssm parameter arn, this is the error I get
Error: ClientException: The repository credentials parameter specified for container 'xxxxx' is invalid. Parameter names can include up to 255 (uppercase and lowercase), numbers, hyphens, and underscores are allowed. Spaces are not allowed.

Comment: Interesting. I would say to try using the parameter name instead of its ARN, but that wouldn't work for most cases either since the parameter name usually has `/` in it since it's like a path, and that error message suggests `/` wouldn't be allowed. You might want to open an issue on the [Terraform AWS provider GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=Bug_Report.md). Alternatively, if you have an AWS support plan, give them the request ID to check for the specific issue.